# Paypal standard checkout from sandbox to production

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

If written a simple paypal standard checkout which sends a form to

```
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?
```

together with get variables like items, tax, adress, business, redirect URL, etc.

Under developer.paypal.com I have one paypal-facilitator@... & paypal-buyer@... account. (The facilitator is used as business variable in my URL).

After a lot of testing everything runs smooth and ready for production. My Question is how do I bring this live? Does it suffice to use

```
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?
```

as Checkout URL? Or do I have to recreate the facilitator account in some paypal production environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply replace the url "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?" with "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?" it will switch to live mode, please also make sure that you use Live PayPal account credentials as the sandbox/facilitator accounts will not work in live mode.